# Can I use a 5 gallon carboy for a 3 gallon batch of wine?

Tags: secondary-fermentation, wine, carboy

I have a 3 gallon wine kit about ready to go from primary in a plastic bucket to secondary in a carboy. This is a port style, so I think I should be getting more fermentation action once I'm in the carboy. I only have a 5 gallon carboy, is this going to be too big and have too much headroom for good results?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that will be fine.  I've done it several times.

Comment: That's right - primary ferment will produce many times more CO2 than the 2 gallons of headspace. However, you may have to condition in bottles, since that's normally done in a carboy matching the batch size.

Comment: Yeah, for long term aging a smaller carboy would be better.  Unless there's some way to purge the O2 from a larger one.

Comment: Doesn't the CO2 sink to the bottom of the gas mix anyways? Unless he moves the carboy it should form a protective layer on top of his wine.

Comment: It's not that cut and dried.  There will definitely be mixing.